# Trying to understand redirect route example

Tags: angular2-routing

From the docs
https://angular.io/guide/router

What does the route with '**' do? What do the two asterisks correspond to?

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',        component: HeroListComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick glance of the documentation, I assume it is a wildcard route.

Quote from the docs: 
'Leave the default and the wildcard routes! These are concerns at the top level of the application itself.'

'Each routing module augments the route configuration in the order of import... 
The wildcard route — which matches every URL — will intercept the attempt to navigate to a hero route.'

Answer (score 0):

It is a [wildcard route](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration). A catch-all for any URL not matched above it.

You do not have to have one of these but if you don't, when the user navigates to a bad route, he/she will NOT see a 404. They'll see a blank page which is just confusing.

This gives us the opportunity to provide them with a message -- a much better UX!